# How to access local variable inside a function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing an android app in Kotlin, i created functions to get the location longitude and latitude and save them in variables, and all is set up, now i want to send these variables with another variables to firebase database, so i created a function to send data to firebase when called, and a data class inside, i tried to make the mlong and mlat global, but it keeps showing me 0.0 for the longitude and latitude when sent to firebase which means longit and latit var is never changed.

here is my activity code when i set "mlong" and "mlat" as global variables :

```
package com.example.getlocation


import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.example.getlocation.SplashActivity.Companion.saveUF
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Looper
import android.provider.Settings
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.*




class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val PERMISSION_ID = 42

lateinit var mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

var mlat = 0.0
var mlong = 0.0

//firebase database
val mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val mRef = mDatabase.getReference("user").child("messages")


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //the font
    val typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "Arslan-Wessam-B.ttf")
    // Set the typeface
    appName.typeface = typeface

    buSync.setOnClickListener {

        insertToFirebase()
    }
}



@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun getLastLocation() {
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {

            mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                var location: Location? = task.result
                if (location == null) {
                    requestNewLocationData()
                } else {
                    mlat = location.latitude
                    mlong = location.longitude
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    } else {
        requestPermissions()
    }
}

//get location
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun requestNewLocationData() {
    var mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
    mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    mLocationRequest.interval = 0
    mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 0
    mLocationRequest.numUpdates = 1

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    mFusedLocationClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
        mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
        Looper.myLooper()
    )
}

private val mLocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
        var mLastLocation: Location = locationResult.lastLocation
        mlong = mLastLocation.latitude
        mlat = mLastLocation.longitude
    }
}

private fun isLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
    var locationManager: LocationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
    )
}

private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

private fun requestPermissions() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        this,
        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
        PERMISSION_ID
    )
}


override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_ID) {
        if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            getLastLocation()
        }
    }
}


fun insertToFirebase() {

    //get user location test
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    getLastLocation()

    data class Insert(
        var et: String? = "",
        var un: String? = "",
        var msg: String? = "",
        var longit: Double? = 0.0,
        var latit: Double? = 0.0
    )

    //get shared preferences
    saveUF = getSharedPreferences("com.example.getlocation", MODE_PRIVATE)
    //get username value from shared preferences
    var username = saveUF?.getString("userName", "")



    //insert data to the object
    var insert = Insert(etUserNameTest.text.toString(), username, "hello", mlong, mlat)

    mRef.push().setValue(insert)
}
}
```

i also found a bad way to do this which is to change:

```
        mlong = mLastLocation.latitude
        mlat = mLastLocation.longitude
```

to this:

```
        textview1.text = mLastLocation.latitude.toString()
        textview2.text = mLastLocation.longitude.toString()
```

and then read the text inside textview1 and textview2 and save it in var and send it to firebase database, but it's a bad way to do this

is there anyway to make mlong and mlat updated by location functions, or define them inside the location function and use them out?

**EDIT(SOLVED):** there is no problem with the code but on the button click the location is not brought yet and it's default value is sent to firebase, so i had to click two times, or to call the function from oncreate, or the best way is by making a callback when location is brought and while that put a progressbar or something, and that's it

Comment: You should define two variables at global level and update them inside the function. After that you can use it easily wherever you want.

Comment: mlong and mlat are global, i updated them inside location function, but the update is only local, it's never changed outside

Comment: I would say to put the reserved word `this` to set them and assure you are setting the global variables. Like `this.mlat` or `this.mlong`

Comment: try debugging it with break points. See if all of expected places are reached.

Comment: Try to print lat long over here `else {
                    mlat = location.latitude
                    mlong = location.longitude
                }`